# Auto Property synthesis will not synthesise property 'description' because it is read write in ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was creating a model for a json data that i will receive from a web service and declaring properties to represent array members from the json array and i declared several properties in objective-c

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *channel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *urlPrefix;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *filename;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *audio_stream;
```

the compiler gave a warning on the *description property that

Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'description' because it is read write but will be synthesize readonly via another property
What is the implication of this. and is there something I'm not doing right?

Comment: @euvs answer below is correct.  To expand; the `description` method was a really bad decision when it was added to the API in ~1994 and we've been living with it ever since.   Treat `description` as verboten.   Use a different property name.

Answer (score 7):

**Case 1 :**

Because `NSString *description` is implicitly declared in `NSString.h` as `readonly` property. This is AutoSynthesized with readonly access. If you want to Synthesize it with readWrite then please synthesize manually.

You declared description as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
```

which in behaviour is of type `readWrite`.

While NSString.h declared description as readonly.

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *description;
```

If you still want to use `description` as `readWrite` then please Synthesise it manually in `YourClassName.m` file .

Add this line in .m file.

```
@synthesize description;
```

**Case : 2**

Use another name other then `description` to use it with `readWrite` access.

Comment: If answer finds helpful, then please mark it as accepted. So, others will also finds it helpful. Thanks

Comment: `NSString`'s declaration of a `description` property has nothing to do with a random subclass of `NSObject`.   It would only matter if OP were subclassing `NSObject`.

Comment: @bbum : Thanks for suggest actual behaviour of Language. I edited answer. Thanks

Comment: Almost got it;  the issue is that OP's problem has *nothing to do with the declaration of `description` on `NSString`*.   The problem is that `NSObject` declares a `readonly` `@property` named `description` and OP's class inherits from `NSObject`.  Any mention of `NSString` is not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are defining those properties in a class that eventually inherits from NSObject. NSObject class conforms to `<NSObject>` protocol which defines `description` property as read only.

```
@protocol NSObject
...
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *description
@end
```

See documentation for `<NSObject>`:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description

You are trying to define a read/write property that has already been defined as read-only in the super-class, hence getting a conflict.

I suggest you to use a different name to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to technerd's answer,

There are 2 ways you can handle this situation.

1) You can rename the property from description to some other property name. (as mentioned by technerd)

2) You can add @synthesize to create the getter and setter in the subclass if you want the same name.

Personally I would prefer the first way.